# What is the complete (polynomial) factorization of $\sigma(p^k)$, where $p$ is prime with $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, divisor-sum

The title says it all.

> What is the complete (polynomial) factorization of $\sigma(p^k)$, where $p$ is prime with $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Here, $\sigma = \sigma_{1}$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.

**My Attempt**

$$\sigma(p^k) = 1 + p + \ldots + p^{k-1} + p^k = \left(1+p\right)\left(1 + p^2 + \ldots + p^{k-1}\right) = \sigma(p)\left(1 + p^2 + \ldots + p^{k-1}\right)$$

Note that $\sigma(p^k) = \sigma(p)$ if $k=1$.

Now, the finite geometric series
$$1 + p^2 + \ldots + p^{k-1}$$
has $n=\dfrac{k-1}{2}+1=\dfrac{k+1}{2}$ terms, and common ratio $r=p^2$.  Thus, we have
$$1 + p^2 + \ldots + p^{k-1} = \dfrac{\left(p^2\right)^{(k+1)/2} - 1}{p^2 - 1} = \dfrac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^2 - 1} = \dfrac{\left(p^{(k+1)/2}+1\right)\left(p^{(k+1)/2}-1\right)}{p^2 - 1}.$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$\sigma(p^k) = \sigma(p)\left(\dfrac{\left(p^{(k+1)/2}+1\right)\left(p^{(k+1)/2}-1\right)}{p^2 - 1}\right).$$

**Question**

> Is $\sigma(p^k)$ when given as
>   $$\sigma(p^k) = \sigma(p)\left(\dfrac{\left(p^{(k+1)/2}+1\right)\left(p^{(k+1)/2}-1\right)}{p^2 - 1}\right)$$
>   considered *completely* factored?

By *complete factorization*, I mean:
$$\bf{e.g.} \hspace{0.5in} x^4 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2 + 1).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k=1$ then we just have the irreducible polynomial $\sigma(p) = 1 + p$, and your second factor cancels out to just $1$.  So we will assume that $k > 1$.

Have a look at [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial): in general, the polynomial $\sigma(p^k) = 1 + p + \cdots + p^k = (p^{k+1}-1)/(p-1)$ will factor over $\mathbb Q[p]$ exactly as $\prod_{d\mid k+1, d>1} \Phi_d(p)$, with the $d=1$ term having been cancelled by the $p-1$ denominator.  In the particular case that $k\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, you will always get the factor $\Phi_2(p) = 1+p = \sigma(p)$, and if $(k+1)/2$ happens to be prime then your other factors correspond roughly to the irreducible factors

$$\Phi_{k+1}(p) = 1 - p + p^2 - \cdots + p^{(k-1)/2},$$
$$\Phi_{(k+1)/2}(p) = 1 + p + p^2 + \cdots + p^{(k-1)/2}.$$

However in the typical case where $(k+1)/2$ is *not* prime, then the polynomial is certainly not completely factored by your attempt.  The first time this happens (subject to the modular restriction on $k$) is when $k=17$:

$$\sigma(p^{17}) = \Phi_2(p) \Phi_3(p) \Phi_6(p) \Phi_9(p) \Phi_{18}(p) \\ = (p+1)(p^2+p+1)(p^2-p+1)(p^6+p^3+1)(p^6-p^3+1).$$

By the way, there seems to be no point whatsoever in specifying that $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, since you are only treating $p$ as an indeterminate.

Comment: My apologies for bothering you again @ErickWong, but I was just revisiting this question (and your answer), and noticed that you did not say anything explicit about the case when $(k+1)/2$ is the *unit* $1$.  Can you please add in more information regarding that case to your answer?

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris Hi Arnie, I imagine that the case $k=1$ is quite similar to the prime case.  Are you mostly asking this to make the answer fully self-contained, or is there something interesting to be said?

Comment: From what I have read in elementary number theory textbooks (e.g. Burton), the unit, primes, and composites are considered distinct, hence my question to you, @ErickWong.  And yes, I would say that I asked it to make your answer fully self-contained, and that there is something interesting to be said (i.e. with respect to the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture on odd perfect numbers).

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris Ok, I added a brief sentence for the case $k=1$, which is the only time $(k+1)/2$ is a unit.

Comment: Thank you, @ErickWong!

Comment: Since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, is it not the case that $$p + 1 = 2\bigg(\frac{p+1}{2}\bigg),$$ and therefore $p+1$ is *not irreducible*, @ErickWong?

Comment: Or am I just confusing the terms *factorable* and *reducible*?

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris The question asks explicitly for the **polynomial** factorization.  $p+1$ is a degree one polynomial and thus irreducible.  Even if we choose to care about scalar factors like $2$, the polynomial $p+1$ is monic and therefore not divisible by $2$ in $\mathbb Z[p]$.  We could divide by $2$ in $\mathbb Q[p]$ but then $2$ would be a unit and still irrelevant to reducibility.

Comment: I reiterate my comment at the end of the original answer: when you are looking at polynomial factorization, you are by definition treating $p$ as an indeterminate, and so it is somewhat meaningless to specify that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  It would be like asking if we can factor $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$ differently depending on whether $x > 1$.